# Connecting to Bitfinex API from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, api, rest, google-apps-script

I'm trying to connect my google sheet to Bitfinex through the 'authenticated' section of the API so I can access my account information. Here is the API [link](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/docs/rest-auth).

I haven't been able to get the 'request' or 'crypto' libraries to work so I've been trying to use other available functions in google sheets, but am having trouble.

Following is the code snippet I'm using:

```
  var completeURL = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos";
  var nonce = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);

  var body = {
    'request' : completeURL,
    'nonce' : nonce
  };

  var payload = JSON.stringify(body).toString('base64');
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_384,
                                                 payload,
                                                 secret);

  signature = signature.map(function(byte) {
    return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }).join('');

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'X-BFX-APIKEY': key,
      'X-BFX-PAYLOAD': payload,
      'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': signature
    },
  }

  Logger.log(completeURL);
  Logger.log(params);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(completeURL, params);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

I get the following error from the API:

> Request failed for https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"message":"Invalid json."} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response). (line 209, file "Code")

And the following are the values from the Logger.log calls:

```
[17-09-24 16:22:28:170 AEST] https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos
[17-09-24 16:22:28:171 AEST] {headers={X-BFX-PAYLOAD={"request":"https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos","nonce":1506234148}, X-BFX-SIGNATURE=06d88a85098aefbf2b56af53721506863978f9350b1b18386c23f446254789dbbfc1eeb520bdfc7761b30f98ea0c21a2, X-BFX-APIKEY=ak6UoPiwaLjwt2UqDzZzZGjpb9P2opvdPCAIqLy0eVq}}
```

I'm stuck and not sure what else to try?

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below if it helped you ...

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification? Since I have no `secret`, I couldn't debug this sample. So I don't know whether this modified sample works. I'm sorry.

### Modification points :

1. `secret` is not defined.
2. When POST method is used, it requires to include `method: "post"` to `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.
3. When it reads Javascript sample of [the document](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/docs/rest-auth), `signature` has to be modified.
4. When it reads Javascript sample of [the document](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/docs/rest-auth), `body: JSON.stringify(body)` is included in the request parameters.
5. There is an error message of `{"message":"Invalid json."}`.

The script which was reflected above modifications is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
var secret = "#####"; // Please input this.

var completeURL = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos";
var nonce = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var body = {
  'request' : completeURL, // I don't know whether this is the correct value.
  'nonce' : nonce
};

var payload = Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(body)).getDataAsString());
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_384, payload, secret);
signature = signature.map(function(byte) {
  return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}).join('');

var params = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {
    'X-BFX-APIKEY': key,
    'X-BFX-PAYLOAD': payload,
    'X-BFX-SIGNATURE': signature
  },
  payload: JSON.stringify(body),
  contentType: "application/json",
  muteHttpExceptions: true
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(completeURL, params);
var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding your code, but if I do, there is at least one oddity at first sight:

In `computeHmacSignature(...)`, you are using the variable `secret` which has not been initialized or even declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works

```
  var body = {
    'request' : "/v1/balances",
    'nonce' : nonce,
    'options':{}
  };
```